# PostgreSQL: count all grouped by month including gaps

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I have a pretty simple query to do - a table has a date field and I need to select count of all rows, grouped by month including gaps.

I have the following query that works for days, but it does not work for month

```
SELECT f.date::date as period, count(e.id) as count
FROM generate_series((now() - interval '1 year')::date, now()::date, '1 month'::interval) AS f(date)
LEFT JOIN my_table AS e ON e.created_at::date = f.date::date
GROUP BY f.date
ORDER BY f.date DESC;
```

For some reason this query returns zero's for all rows.

This query works, but it does not fill in gaps

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS txn_month, count(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY txn_month
```

What is the right way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the number of rows in `my_table` for each period, including periods without corresponding data in `my_table`.

```
WITH agg_periods AS (
  SELECT s.period_start, s.period_start + p.agg_interval AS period_end
    FROM (SELECT 'P1M'::interval AS agg_interval) p
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()) - 'P1Y'::interval, now(), p.agg_interval) s(period_start)
)
SELECT f.period_start AS period, count(e.id) AS COUNT
  FROM agg_periods f
  LEFT JOIN my_table e
    ON f.period_start <= e.created_at
       AND e.created_at < f.period_end
 GROUP BY f.period_start
 ORDER BY f.period_start;
```

The query is structured so that different periods can be accomodated by changing the period generation parameters in the subquery, `agg_periods`. Because `created_at` is used without type casts in the comparisons, PostgreSQL isn't prevented from using indexes on that column.